# JPA findBy method always goes to orElseThrow

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, option-type, findby

This is our code

```
private IdentificationMaster validateIdentificationType(String idType) {
    if(!StringUtils.isNotBlank(idType))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid idType");

    Optional<IdentificationMaster> op1 = specRepo.findById(idType); //testing purpose

    Optional<IdentificationMaster> op2 = specRepo.findByIdentificationType(idType); //testing purpose

    return specRepo.findById(idType)
            .orElse(specRepo.findByIdentificationType(idType)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Id Type Not Found " + idType)));
}
```

For `idType` we're expecting two values it can either be **primary key id** or its corresponding `identificationType`. Table only has two columns `id` and `identificationType`. The problem is that it throws `ResourceNotFoundException` even if `op1` or `op2` is not empty. Now if I change my return like this

```
return specRepo.findByIdentificationType(idType)
            .orElse(specRepo.findById(idType)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Id Type Not Found " + idType)));
```

Its again throwing the same exception!

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface IdentificationSpecRepository extends CrudRepository<IdentificationMaster, String>{

    Optional<IdentificationMaster> findByIdentificationType(String identificationType);
}
```

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "IDENTIFICATION_MASTER")
public class IdentificationMaster {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;


    @Column(name = "IDENTIFICATION_TYPE", unique = true)
    private String identificationType;

    // getters and setters

}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: can you post on how specRepo is written?

Comment: do you get the value with op1.get() for testing purpose?

Comment: Ya @MPhil I'm getting value

Comment: can you also post the IdentificationMaster?

Comment: Hey Arun, please find my answer to your question. Feel free to ask for clarification in the comment section :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
return specRepo.findByIdentificationType(idType)
            .orElse(specRepo.findById(idType)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("...")));
```

Is the reason.

Java is quite eager in execution and always calls the orElse method to prepare just in case it would need it.

The order of your execution is somehow:

1. `specRepo.findByIdentificationType(idType)`
2. `orElse` cannot be executed as it's argument is not evaluated yet
3. `specRepo.findById(idType)`
4. `.orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("..."))`
5. The result of 3 and 4 becomes an object `o`
6. `orElse(o)`

Instead of using `orElse` one should prefer `orElseGet`.

```
return specRepo.findByIdentificationType(idType)
            .orElseGet(() -> specRepo.findById(idType)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("...")));
```

It will only be called when needed.

We have two scenarios here:

1. `specRepo` returns an non-empty Optional.
2. `specRepo` returns empty object.

In scenario 1, `idType` is a valid `identificationType` thus is not an `id`, so the `findById` will throw an exception.
In scenario 2, `idType` is not a valid `identificationType` and if it is a legal `id` the method should result in exception being thrown.

#### Edit:

While this answers diagnoses the problem and describes what is the reason of such behavior, `@Abinash Ghosh` answer provides the simplest and imo best solution of the problem.

In general, avoid using `orElse`. In this case, add the `findByIdentificationTypeOrId(String it, String id)` to your repository.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it cuts deep to certain concepts and was certainly the answer what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

@xenteros is right that is the problem.
You can use `findByIdentificationTypeOrId` to get data in one query

```
return specRepo.findByIdentifcationTypeOrId(idType, idType)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("...")));
```

and repository like

```
@Repository
public interface IdentificationSpecRepository extends CrudRepository<IdentificationMaster, String>{

    Optional<IdentificationMaster> findByIdentificationTypeOrId(String identificationType, String id);
}
```

Comment: Good catch. I diagnosed the issue, you came up with a beautiful solution.

Comment: @Abinash Ghosh, thanks for the answer, its precise and faster in execution and I've given my 1+ for it. But my quest really was for why its going to throws condition? So I've to accept the other answer, I hope you understand.